# Is my understanding of the word "Malaise" correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

The word "malaise" has three definitions, according to Merriam Webster.

Definitions of malaise -

1: an indefinite feeling of debility or lack of health often indicative of or accompanying the onset of an illness

An infected person will feel a general malaise.

2: a vague sense of mental or moral ill-being

a malaise of cynicism and despair

3: a problem or condition that harms or weakens a group, society, etc.

[noncount]

postwar malaise

[singular]

The country's current economic problems are symptoms of a deeper malaise.

The general premise of the first two meanings seems to refer to a slump in which you feel sick either mentally or physically. The last definition seems to refer to a slump that everyone collectively is plagued by, like an economic slump or education slump or a political slump.

Is my understanding of these definitions completely off the mark? Please correct my understanding, if there are any errors.

Comment: Those are pretty close.  Note that "malaise" is used as a metaphor of sorts, taking the literal sense of "sickness" and stretching it to apply to situations where no literal sickness is present.

Comment: So is "malaise" the problem or ailment that is seen as causing the slumps?

Comment: "Malaise" is the condition that results.

Comment: How is "malaise" the resulting condition. If malaise takes on the literal sense of "sickness" would it not stand to reason that it is the cause of the condition, rather than the resulting condition?

Comment: Malaise is not the sickness itself; it’s the state caused by the sickness. (Or it’s a state resembling one caused by an illness) This can be seen in its etymology: “mid 18th century: ‘from French, from Old French mal ‘bad’ (from Latin malus ) + aise ‘ease’.“ Malaise refers to feeling ill at ease, not to the cause of this feeling. Sense 3 seems to be an extension of this earlier sense of the word.

Comment: *Malaise* could be the cause of a problem, too, e.g., imagine that morale is poor in a certain company.  We can say there is a general malaise among the workers in the company.  This could contribute to a bankruptcy. / Basically, when a person or group feels bad in an existential or general sort of way, and they are internalizing the bad feeling (not going around screaming or flipping tables), we can talk about the bad feeling as a *malaise*.  Also, a *malaise* is often a **non-specific** or sort of **fuzzy** bad feeling. (As opposed to, e. g., *nausea*, which is a specific bad feeling.)